# Need to change format of a string for CouchDB auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I have created multiple user documents in the _users database with the following in the "name" property:

```
"johnny.weng.luu@gmail.com"
"mammamia"
"mamma/mia"
"mamma:mia"
```

I logged in each one of them (the password is the same for all of them) and then I tried to get the current user session with GET /_session with cookie auth.

It worked for the first 3 documents but not for the 4th one.

The conclusion is that if I have a : in the "name" it won't work.

So now I want to change the format of the "name" value so that it won't have the : in there. Is this about encryption or encoding and how do I do that in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use javascript's native string replace function:

```
var name = "mamma:mia";
name = name.replace(/:/g, ''); // name = mammamia
```

this will replace all occurences of ":" with nothing
then you would need to update your database with the new names and maybe prevent users from using such characters in the future

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But if I want to change the format instead, how should I do that?